# DismissViewControllerAnimated is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Working with local push notifications if the notification receives its move to `NotificationViewcontroller` there is no notification it moves the `main view controller` .
Here I'm using code:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
 {

    if ([status isEqualToString:@"YES"])
    {
        NotificationViewcontroller *notify_view =[[NotificationViewcontroller alloc]init];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:notify_view animated:YES completion:nil];
```

when i use this code means it should not move to `NotificationViewcontroller` i got this `errorr:`
 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

```
   // self.window.rootViewController=notify_view;
```

i use this code it move to `NotificationViewcontroller`. after seeing the notification put one back button to go view controller

```
    NSLog(@"Go to some other view");


}
else
{
    [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES  completion:nil];
}
```

After see the notification put one back button to go `view controller` that back button is not working.

```
-(IBAction)back_btn:(id)sender
{
[self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES  completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: If you're new to development, you should be reading the documentation. Start with the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are setting the rootviewcontroller as NotificationViewcontroller , so on press of back button change the rootviewcontroller as some other view controller.
- Because there is no view hierarchy, to dismiss the view controller.
- presentviewcontroller is used to open new viewcontroller from existing viewcontroller, then only you can dismiss your presentedviewcontroller and it will go back to your parent(e.g.) viewcontroller.

Comment: how to get the solution for this? need back back button? help me?

Comment: Inside back btn method:  appdelegateobj.window.rootViewController = destination vc obj. Thats all

Comment: dashview its my application want to move that class. want to write back btn code in NotificationViewcontroller...

Comment: dashview its my application want to move that class. want to write back btn code in NotificationViewcontroller...

Comment: dashview is the rootview of ur app or some other view.??

Comment: No... NotificationViewcontroller is root view.... if there is no notification receives when the user click the app icon is move to dash view... notification recive means it move to NotificationViewcontroller.. want need back button in NotificationViewcontroller.. help me??..

Comment: make dash view as root viewcontroller...simple...if notification received make NotificationViewcontroller as root view..